# Role of service layer in Spring (clarification)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I would like to clarify the role of the service layer in my mind. I have a classic architecture for my app :
Controller => Service => DAO (JpaRepository).

The service perform my business logic and are annotated with @Transactional.

Let's take a simple example and say that I have two entities:

- Company
- Project

A company can have several project and a project can be in one company. Let's assume that there is one controller for each entity.
For example, if I want to get all the projects of one company, I have two options.

1. Calling **ProjectService** in my **CompanyController** and create a method in the ProjectService that get all projects by a company ID (by a query in the DAO). Then, I will have several @Autowired (for all services) in my controller but only one in my service.
2. Adding a FindAllProject in my CompanyService that will call the project DAO method. Then, I will have only one @Autowired in my controller but several in my service.

What would be the best approach ?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Seb

Comment: Perhaps `ProjectService`, `CompanyService`, and `CompanyController` have too much responsibility?  Maybe there should be finer grained implementations such as `ProjectSearchService`, `CompanySearchController`,  and `CompanySearchService`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether there is a best practice for this. I would like to go for the 1st option. The reason is:

Service is responsible for business logic. Your requirement is get the `Projects List` from a `Company`, the returned result is a `List` of **`Projects`**.

The `ProductService` layer then just need to call one `ProductDAO` which is responsible for `Product` only

With that in mind, when the methods increase, just remember: What do you want to get as returned result?

- A `Project` so you go for `ProjectService`
- A `Company` so you go for `CompanyService`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please refrain from asking questions in another question's answer. I understand you cannot comment due to your rep so it might be best to rephrase your question and ask it in a separate thread.

Comment: Ah sorry if that make you think it's a question. My answer is 1st option. I just want to see his reply after more than 1 year leaving it.